# How to get all visible tabs in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know that for a tab to be visible, it must be the `active` tab in its window. However, a tab could be visible on the screen, but not be in the `lastFocusedWindow`.

Using `const tabList = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true});` will give me the tab the user is currently focused on (if they type on their keyboard, the words would show up on this tab).

However, the user might have another window open on their screen, so they would be able to see another tab at the same time. I want to get these tabs too.

Comment: maybe cutting off  _lastFocusedWindow: true_ ?

Comment: You want to get tab1 and tab2 if tab1 is active on Window1 and tab2 is active on Windows2?

Comment: did you searched chrome.windows API. it has getAll getCurrent, getLastFocused methods that can be useful for you